# Using hidden field id selector to load text in another field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I have a hidden input in a form

```
<td>
<input id="total" class="totalD" type="hidden" value="$394,655.00">
</td>
```

I want to display this value in another cell

```
<td><input type="text"" class="" name="sum"  id="tDir" value="" /></td>
```

Using following jquery

```
  $("#total").val($('#tDir').val());
```

It wont load the value in id=tDir. 
Please let me know how to fix it. THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually the reverse process:

```
$( '#tDir' ).val($( '#total' ).val());
```

Right now in your code, you are trying to load the `tDir` input value into the hidden field with ID as `total`, but as per your requirement you need to do the reverse.

Answer (score 2):

Your markup is broken, you have an extra quote in your textbox:

```
<input type="text"" class="" name="sum"  id="tDir" value="" />
                  ^
```

If you meant to set the input box value from the hidden input (and not the other way round), it needs to be:

```
$("#tDir").val($('#total').val());
```

Either way, the markup needs fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the HTML. This is the correct format:

```
  <td><input type="text" class="" name="sum"  id="tDir" value="" /></td>
```

You had an extra quote on "type".

Answer (score 0):

Fix **HTML** issue

```
<td><input type="text" class="" name="sum"  id="tDir" value="" /></td>
```

Using **JQuery**

```
$("#tDir").val($('#total').val());
```